# Relation between Weekly ATR and daily ATR?

Tags: equities, technical-analysis

I will need to use weekly ATR (ATR computed using weekly HLC data) to compute some technical indicators on a daily time scale. But instead of directly computing the weekly ATR, it is more convenient to compute daily ATR (ATR computed using daily HLC data), and the quote data are in daily time frame. Is there a straightforward relation between the two (for example, weekly ATR may be approximately daily ATR times a constant)?

Comment: From the 5 daily bars (MTWThF) you can construct a weekly bar, and from the weekly bars you can calculate weekly ATR straightforwardly. I do not recommend "converting" daily ATR to weekly by multiplying by a constant, it is likely to give a very imprecise result.

Comment: The problem is that I am doing analysis on a daily scale. On Tuesday, what the weekly ATR should be? It is ambiguous. I could use the weekly ATR for the past week (ending on Friday). Or I resegment the weeks by considering each week from Tues to the next Monday. Then use this definition to compute the new weekly ATR. Also, when I compute weekly ATR in this way, I basically omit daily open and close data in the middle of the week. But a daily ATR using 5 x the  number of days will use those middle day open and close data. Intuitively, the daily ATR with 5 x longer periods seems to be better.